# New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions

Tags: ios, xcode, submit, app-store-connect

Today Apple release  iOS 10. and I am about to submit my new update of the app. However, when click the "Submit for Review" button on itunesconnect, it shows

[image]

that really confuses me because my Mac OS and Xcode is not developer beta version.

[image]

So is there anyone who has the same issue and may i ask how you solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS 10.12 GM seed cannot be used for prod http://www.apple.com/in/macos/sierra/

You can wait till 21st september when it releases officially or revert back to previous Mac build. Your Xcode version is ok